# Submit Button in apple developer agreement is not responding

Tags: ios, xcode, safari, xcode7

[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Syyan.png) I try to download Xcode for my mac , During installation i have to confirm apple developer agreement . But after agree the terms and conditions, submit button is not responding. I am using OS 10.10.5 and safari 10.0.2 versions. So i can't go forward to download the same. can you help me?

Comment: Please share a screen shot. If agreement lies on developer portal then try  after clearing cache and browser history.Optionally login from developer portal and download from there , it will redirect you in itunes and you can proceed the process again

Comment: Which Xcode version you are trying to download ?

Comment: Xcode version 7.2.1

Comment: I just cleared cache and browser history, but again it won't work..

Comment: Did you try scrolling down the agreement till the last line?

Comment: Xcode 7.1.1 is the Maximum Xcode Version compatible with Yosemite 10.10.5. Check https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/26049

Comment: Yes, I did it till the last line...But no way...

Comment: i think its not a version problem, when i try to install 8 then it shows error popup...

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? Currently having this same problem in Sept. 2018.

Comment: And in December 2018. Doesn't work on Windows (Firefox) Mac OS (Safari and Chrome). Any solution?

Comment: January 2019, still not working on Mac OS(Chrome and Safari), did anyone figure this out yet?

Comment: I think you can also confirm Xcode T&C via the line command... (I assume that is the same agreement, based on the question's description...)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It appears to happen on `Mac OS`. Try to submit that agreement on any other OS like `Windows`, `Android` etc on the Apple Developer website with your Apple account. After submitting, come back to your MacBook and try to login and it should work.

Comment: I had to submit the T&C request on my phone. Pretty ironic bug, if we're being real.